# Automatic population of combobox by MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

I have a database with two tables:

- one for region
- one for provinces

I want to create a page with two comboboxes.
The first one is automatic populated with all the records of the table region. When I choose a record I want to populate the second combobox with all the provinces of the region without refresh the page.
Is there a method to do it using PHP and MySQL?

Comment: If you use some AJAX and jquery, then it's possible..

Comment: [Here](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list3.php) is the perfect example for you!!

Answer (score 0):

use Ajax , send the chosen value from the first combobox to another script.php using Ajax  where you will get the needed values ,then insert it in the innerHTML of the second combobox